# What kind of hash/data does acts_as_taggable_on output, and how can I extract a list of tag ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, save, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggable_on in an app and I would like to extract the tag ids (not the tag names) that a post has been tagged with.

My app has a posts controller, and in ruby console I can do:

```
 >> post = Post.find(1)
   => #<Post id: 1, content: "Aliquam cupiditate ea deserunt et id placeat molest...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-07-06 19:29:44", updated_at: "2011-07-06 19:29:44">
 >> tags = post.tag_counts_on("topics")
   => [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "Politics">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "Economics">]
```

Here I have shown that the post is tagged with topic ids "Politics" and "Economics". My problem is, I want to save this information on a cookie for use later. But I can't store a hash on a cookie, I can only store strings of information. If I do:

```
 session[:store_name] = tags.join(",")
```

And then later:

```
 tags = session[:store_name].split(",")
```

I will get a hash:

```
 ["Politics", "Economics", ...]
```

But this hash doesn't have a record of the tag_id for each topic tag. Is there any way to pull the ids out at some point and save them for later with the acts_as_taggable_on output? Or some suggestions on how to preserve the output from acts_as_taggable_on for later use?

Comment: if you need the ids, just do tags.map(&:id).join(",")

Comment: thanks, that's a simple solution. what kind of has is the acts_as_taggable_on outputting? how would one replicate that?

Comment: iwhat do you mean what kind of hash is it outputting? acts as taggable is giving you an array of actsastaggable objects

Comment: yeah, missed the misspelt word there. Alright, thanks for all the help, corroded!

Comment: corroded - if you want to put your first comment as an answer rather than a comment, i'd happily check-mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the id's, just do

```
tags.map(&:id).join(",")
```